# Laravel 9 whereHas take long time to execute

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing a large problem with a huge query. It take a long time to execute this one.

```php
$project
    ->quotes()
    ->where('status', '!=', QuoteStatus::DRAFT)
    ->with(['credit' => fn ($query) => $query->active()])
    ->whereHas('credit', fn ($query) => $query->active())
    ->paginate(10)
```

```php
class Quote extends Model {
    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->has('quote.signature');
    }
}
```

The problem come from the line:

```php
->whereHas('credit', fn ($query) => $query->active())
```

What I would like in this request:
Get all `Credit`s with the scope "active".
Credit is in the relationship: `project.quoteS.credit` - each quote CAN (not "must") have a credit.
Probably I'm doing something badly in this request that I don't fully understand.. So if someone can help me ? :slight_smile:

Comment: Do you know how to write what is intended in DB::RAW?
If so, we could probably understand it more. Currently, I've got no clue why you use that whereHas. You can also define an relationship with requirements on specific coulmns etc.

Comment: This whereHas constraint my request to get quotes that had a credit active. If you remove the whereHas, there is no constraint and you will get ALL quotes (with and without credits active).

Comment: Try to output sql (->toSql()) and post raw query here

Comment: Since you use `->active()` in `whereHas` you don't need to also use it in `with` keep in mind that `active()` adds quite a lot of querying because it is nested which will result in two nested subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Try this, or whichever data active holds:

```
->whereRelation('credit', 'active', '==', 1)
```

Not sure how effective this is compared to what you've got. Personally, I'd probably change the database a bit so that all inside the table is considered active, and then it gets moved once it is no longer active to another table.